# How to upload Image in server along with other parameters in Swift 3 iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, afhttprequestoperation

##This is my Objective-c code where i have Send image to server.

```
    NSString *str=@"https://user.co/users/";
    NSString *urlString=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str] stringByAppendingString:@"add"];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager1 = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager1.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager1 POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
         [formData appendPartWithFileData:pictureData name:@"profile_pic" fileName:@".jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }

          progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){
              NSLog(@"Response is success : %@", responseObject);
              if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"sucess"]isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
              }else{
              }
          }
           failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
           }];
```

How to achieve this upload Image in server along with other parameters in Swift 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 Alamofire multipart upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592085/swift-3-alamofire-multipart-upload)

Comment: Can I know how to pass Headers ?

Comment: let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Comment: @HarshalValanda Still  image not save on server

Comment: Which error occur?

Comment: JSON: {
    data =     {
        id = 157;
        "last_name" = dkdkdjdjd;
        "phone_no" = 1234566543;
        "profile_pic" = "";
        status = 1;
    };
    message = "User details saved!";
    success = 1;
}

Comment: @HarshalValanda Please check response image still Blank

Comment: its not your problem. its problems in api. you send successfully @Inderpal singh

Comment: @HarshalValanda i have try in objective c its working fine, But i got problem in Swift 3

Comment: Please, provide a objective c and swift code @inderpal singh

Comment: where i provide you code @HarshalValanda ?

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: @HarshalValanda please check objective c Code

Answer (score 0):

try using almofire multipartform data

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in


        for (key, value) in params{

            if key == "profile_pic"{

                let uploadImage = value as! UIImage

                let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadImage)!
                formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData , name: "uploaded_file[]", fileName: "uploadImage\(index)x.png", mimeType: "image/png")



                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "uploadImage", fileName: "uploadImage", mimeType: "image/png")

            }else{

                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, with: URL2, encodingCompletion: { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.data)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                    //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                    self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
                print(encodingError)
            }

        }

    })
```