# I have upgraded my app from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0, i am facing a big issue in resolving Alamofire issues regarding upload request

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I am getting following error on returning value
//Cannot invoke 'upload' with an argument list of type '(URLRequestConvertible, data: NSData)' Pods are updated and i have updated the code as well still facing the same error.[Updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u37LA.png)

```
    if !Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        print("Request:\(baseURL + self.rawValue) \nParams:\(aParams) \n \(imageFileName):[FILE]")
        let alert = SwAlert.generate(Global.Constants.APP_DISPLAY_NAME, message: Global.ConstantsMessages.connectionFailedMsg )
        alert.addAction("Ok", completion: { (resultObject) -> Void in
        })
        alert.show()
        return nil
    }else {
           print("Request:\(baseURL + self.rawValue) \nParams:\(aParams) \n \(imageFileName):[FILE]")
        let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents(baseURL + self.rawValue, parameters: aParams, imageData: imageData, imageFileName:imageFileName )

        return Alamofire.upload(data:urlRequest.1, to: urlRequest.0)

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592085/swift-3-alamofire-multipart-upload

Comment: You have to update pod to 4.0 alteast

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for alamofire upload request in swift 3 is -

`Alamofire.upload(data: Data, to: URLConvertible)`

You are just using the parameters wrongly..

Comment: I am still facing the same issue

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest swift 3 pod of alamofire.

Comment: i am using following one 
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'